# Does anyone know of a rails gem for managing bibliography/references?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Does anyone know of a gem/plugin for rails which can be used to manage bibliography or publication references? This tends to be quite standard format, so I am hoping there is something out there?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it will be useful for you. There is a [Bookchef](https://github.com/snitko/bookchef/) gem, that allows you to generate book (with references and footnotes) out of the xml file. It is convenient if you want to use just your favorite code editor and version control system.

But it has nothing to do with references formatting.